# Datatables Sparkline from column values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatables

In my application I have a `datatable` (datatables.net) the table is getting json data and is populating the table.

One of the column is getting an array of integers, this column needs to hide the integer values and draw a sparkline with the help of those values.

```
 if $('#keys').length
tC = $('#keys')
tC.dataTable
  bJQueryUI: true
  bAutoWidth: false
  bStateSave: false
  iDisplayLength: 25
  oScroller:
    loadingIndicator: true
  fnPreDrawCallback: ->
    responsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(tC, breakpointDefinition) unless responsiveHelper
  fnRowCallback: (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) ->
    responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon nRow
  fnDrawCallback: (oSettings) ->
    responsiveHelper.respond()
    comparekeys();
  bServerSide: true
  sAjaxSource: $('#keys').data('source')
```

This code which is populating my table and the below code is meant to draw the sparklines.

```
 if $('#comp').length
pot_com = $('#pot_com').data('results')
col = 0
while col < pot_com
  spark_pot = $('#comp_pot' + col).data('results')
  new Highcharts.Chart(
    chart:
      renderTo: "com_pot#{col}"
      backgroundColor: 'none'
      defaultSeriesType: "area"
      margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    title: text: false
    credits: enabled: false
    xAxis: labels: false
    yAxis: labels: false
    legend: enabled: false
    tooltip: enabled: false
    exporting: enabled: false
    plotOptions:
      series:
        lineWidth: 1
        shadow: false
        states: hover: lineWidth: 1
        marker:
          enabled: true
          radius: 1
    series: [
      fillColor: "rgb(230, 136, 138)"
      data: spark_pot
    ]
  )
  col++
```

`pot_com = $('#pot_com').data('results')` is getting the total number of results

`spark_pot = $('#comp_pot' + col).data('results')` is getting the current row values

I was able to use the code for creating the sparkline on a datatable which didn't had any serverside rendering.

How can I add the sparkline on a `datatable` with serverside processing?

Comment: I found a solution on [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline), the only thing which I needed to do was to take the array of values from each row.

Answer (score 0):

This example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/stocks.html) should help - it's generating a sparkline from the data source. Here's the relevant code:

```
            {
                data: 'last',
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span class="sparkline">' + data.toString() + '</span>' :
                        data;
                }
            }
```